# php add scheduled tasks as minutes to current time as 12:10 - 12:19

Tags: php, mysql

I´m making a simple time management system feature and I want to add
task and estimated minutes.

So if I add into the field "finish sending e-mail to John" and "23" (as minutes) it goes into
mysql as `$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule (task, time, timestamp) VALUES ('$_POST[task]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[timestamp]')";`

The output would be " Finish sending e-mail to John   21:02 - 21:25 "
so if next task takes 7 minutes it will be from 21:26 - 21:33" (take notice
of the first task and so and and so forth

I tried `echo date('H:i', strtotime('+["time"] minutes', ));`

but it doesn´t
work and I don´t know how the next record would take notice of the next one

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you tried above is almost correct, except that you might mean `$_POST['time']` instead of `["time"]`, making your code: `echo date ('H:i', strtotime('+{$_POST["time"]} minutes'));`. But that will give you the `time` minutes after current time, not after the starting time.

To get the end time, you need to convert your start time (I assume it's `$_POST['timestamp']`) into UNIX timestamp, then add the task's length and get the UNIX timestamp from it.

Give this a try:

```
// Remember to check for valid user input. I'll leave that for you.
$task = $_POST['task'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];

// Get the time here
$start_time = date ("H:i", strtotime ($timestamp));
$end_time = date ("H:i", strtotime ($timestamp) + $time * 60);

echo "{$task} {$start_time}-{$end_time}\n";
```